# help identify set from parts

Tags: set-identification

Please help me identify which set either of these parts came from (tried using Bricklink but don't know how to describe the bricks to get the correct result)...

[image: grey tri turret]

[image: red lego structure]

Comment: The bottom photo is a Mega Blok set, so isn't likely to show up in Lego set searches...

Answer (score 4):

The first assembly is from the [#8087 LEGO Star Wars TIE Defender](http://brickset.com/sets/8087-1/TIE-Defender) released in 2010.

[image]

The second assembly is not LEGO, but Mega Bloks (Mega Construx).

Comment: Wow, you guys are incredible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're very welcome. :)